# Регулярные выражения. Замена между группой символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql, замена

Нужно сделать замену в строке.

было

```
* one/two * {three} *
```

стало

```
* {one/two} * {three} *
```

Делаю так:

```
[\*](.*?)[\~\*]
```

+ замена на * {\1} *

---

В итоге этот список:

```
* one/two * {three} * 
* one * {tw~/thr~} * fou~ *
* one * {tw~/three} * {fou~/fiv~ si~} *
* {on~/tw~ thre~} * fou~ {fiv~/si~} *
* {on~/~tw~/thre~} * fiv~ *
one * {two} * 
* one * two 
* one * two *
```

Преобразуется к такому:

```
* { one/two } * {three} * 
* { one } * {tw~/thr~} * { fou} * *
* { one } * {tw~/three} * { {fou} */fiv~ si~} *
* { {on} */tw~ thre~} * { fou} * {fiv~/si~} *
* { {on} */~tw~/thre~} * { fiv} * *
one * { {two} } * 
* { one } * two 
* { one } * two *
```

Вот тесты на regexp101 - https://regex101.com/r/ApHQy6/2

Как сделать правильно ?

p.s Находит слова между символами {} - а нужно чтобы искать только между ** - если они не заключены в {}. А так же должен искать в начале строки без *, и в конце строки без **

Comment: Вы пишете код на PHP? Тогда `preg_replace('~{[^{}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\*|^)\s*\K[^{}]+?(?=\s*(?:\*|$))~', '{$0}', $text)`, [пример на многострочном тексте см. на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8Ug7Cj/3)

Comment: Виктор, пишу для Postgres. Спасибо!